# How would I change an image when there is a collision Swift Spritekit?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this bird image and when there is a collision I want to change the image into a different bird image. How would I do this? I know it goes in this function but cant figure out how to do it. Thanks!

```
 func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){
   if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask  
   == EnemyCategory { 


    }
```

Comment: I am not playing so much with Swift, but I guess something like yourNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)

Comment: Yes I just tried that and it worked but the second image is kind of big.